# Should I fix the "PHP Warning: Division by zero" errors? Does it make my server slow?

Tags: php, divide-by-zero

What problem can happen on my server? I'm monitoring a server and that keep occurring on the log file from some web app.

Nothing is show for the users, only on the log file. More than 10 erros when some user open some report pages.

Does this error can crash the server? These errors make the server slow?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you should fix it.

Comment: Scripting languages largely do not crash with such errors. Use a profiler to test performance implications. Fix it for ensuring correct results anyway.

Comment: Yes, always write code so that you handle errors and warnings. Suppressing them isn't a good idea, fixing them is much better. Check if it's zero before you do the division. `if ($denominator != 0) { echo $numerator / $denominator; } else { /* Division by zero, can't divide */ }`

Comment: There is an article about it, in french I believe and someone made a quick translation that with 10000 errors it took about 100 ms longer if I recall correct

Answer (score 0):

The errors won't make the server slower, but will clog up your log files and cause visitors to see 500 errors on the pages affected by the problem. 
Fixing this kind of error should be easy, can you post your code?